# Cannot get reCAPTCHA token onSubmit method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have the following form and try to get token for passing it to the backend (for reCAPTCHA validation).

First, I add the necessary script to `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=my_site_key"></script>
```

Then in my `login.vue` form:

```
<a-button @click="onSubmit">Login</a-button>

<div class="g-recaptcha"
     data-sitekey="my_site_key"
     data-callback="onSubmit"
     data-size="invisible">
</div>


// ...

onSubmit() {
  var t = null;

  grecaptcha.execute().then(function(token) {
    t = token
  });
}
```

In `onSubmit` method, I cannot get `token` and its value is null. I tried some workarounds, but not working properly. So, is there a problem or missing part related to the implementation above? Or how can I pass the necessary parameter (I think I just need to pass token as `g-recaptcha-response`)?

***Update:***

Here is my `onSubmit` method. At `this.login()` line, it throws "*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined at...*" error :(

```
onSubmit() {
  var t = null;
  grecaptcha.execute('my_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {

    const payload = { email: 'admin@admin.com', password: '********' };
    this.login(payload).then((response) => {
      // ...
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: Anyone else using reCAPTCHA with server side validation?

Answer (score 1):

You must also pass the key and the action to the `execute` method.

```
grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {}
```

Then verify the token on the backend.

Doc: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Could you please see my Update? I applied your suggestion but get an error. After fixing it I believe in that I will solve the problem.

Comment: you need to define the login method

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand, Any clarification pls?

Comment: you have used this.login, but have you defined it?

Comment: Yes, of course. I did not add it to the question, because there is no need to add it (the problem is not related to that method).

Comment: Is this for V3?